# IPSEC libreswan interface endpoint does not match left or right

Tags: vpn, raspberry-pi, pfsense, ipsec, strongswan

I am using libreswan on raspberry Pi OS 12 to connect to PFsense with `/etc/ipsec.conf`
from an external network

```
config setup

conn %default
        #keyexchange=ikev1


conn peer-ipsec.xxx.de-tunnel-1
        left=%any
        leftid="xx.zapto.org"
        right=ipsec.xx.de
        rightid="%any"
        leftsubnet=10.130.117.0/24
        rightsubnet=10.128.0.0/16
        ike=aes128-sha256-modp2048
        #,aes128-sha256-modp2048!
        #keyexchange=ikev2
        reauth=no
        ikelifetime=28800s
        esp=aes128-sha256-modp2048
        #,aes128-sha256-modp2048!
        keylife=3600s
        rekeymargin=540s
        type=tunnel
        compress=no
        authby=secret
        auto=route
        keyingtries=%forever
```

(out commented parts are not accepted by libreswan)
After ĺoading secrets from `/etc/ipsec.secrets` (`%any %any : PSK "..."`) I got:

```
interface endpoint [::1]:4500 does not match left(THIS) or right (THAT)
interface endpoint [::1]:500 does not match left(THIS) or right (THAT) 
interface endpoint [127.0.0.1]:4500 does not match left(THIS) or right (THAT) 
interface endpoint [127.0.0.1]:500 does not match left(THIS) or right (THAT) 
interface endpoint [192.168.2.117]:4500 does not match left(THIS) or right (THAT) 
interface endpoint [192.168.2.117]:500 does not match left(THIS) or right (THAT)
```

`ip a` -> 192.168.2.117

The same configuration with the out commented part are working on a EdgeRouter ER-X (ubiquity).

On pfsense: 
Key Exchange version: IKEv2 
InternetProtocol: IPv4 
Remote Gateeway: xx.zapto.org 
Authentication Method: Mutual PSK 
My Identifier: My IP address 
Peer identifier: Fully qualified domain name  xx.zapto.org 
Encryption Algorithm: AES 128 bit SHA256 DH Group 14 (I will improve this later) 
 
Phase 2: 
local network: Network 10.128.0.0/0 
NAT: None 
Remote Network: Network 10.130.117.0/24 
Protocol: ESP 
Encryption Algorithm: AES 128, AES12-GCM 128  SHA256 PFS key group 14

Comment: Are you 100% sure that this config (i.e. the `left=%any`) is what LibreSwan is seeing? (i.e. are you editing this on the correct machine, are you looking at logs on the correct machine, is your LibreSwan build compiled to use /etc and not /usr/local/etc)? You tagged this with [strongswan] – are you following strongSwan manuals or LibreSwan manuals? They have diverged a lot and migth not necessarily have the same config semantics (e.g. strongSwan no longer uses ipsec.conf at all). For that matter, have you considered using strongSwan?

Comment: `sudo /usr/libexec/ipsec/pluto --version`-> `Libreswan 4.10` <br>
`sudo /usr/libexec/ipsec/pluto  --leak-detective --config /etc/ipsec.conf` --nofork -- debug-all` <br/>
I am direct working on the machine so that I do not need a second network interface. I am following libreswan manuals. I also tried `strongswan` before - maybe I should try again?

Comment: strongswan uses `/etc/ipsec.conf` `sudo ipsec start --nofork --debug-more`

```
Loading conn 'p'
00[DMN] Starting IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.9.8, Linux 6.1.0-rpi6-rpi-v7, armv7l)
00[CFG] PKCS11 module '<name>' lacks library path
00[PTS] TPM 2.0 - could not load
00[NET] using forecast interface eth0
00[CFG]
 loaded ca certificate "C=CH, O=ProtonVPN AG"
 loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
   loaded IKE secret for %any %any
 HA config misses local/remote address
 received stroke: add connection 'p'
 added configuration 'p'
 received stroke: route 'p'
'p' routed
```

Comment: I have made a new question about using [StrongSwan](https://superuser.com/questions/1819717/ipsec-strongswan-ha-config-misses-no-connection).

Comment: Using [StrongSwan](https://superuser.com/questions/1819717/ipsec-strongswan-ha-config-misses-no-connection) it works. (`auto = start`)